# Radiobutton only shows one option

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it seems that my radiobutton only shows one option instead of two options(which is what I originally wanted).

```
PLAYERS = [("Black", "black"),
           ("White", "white")]

def first_player(self) -> str:

    self.firstplayer = tkinter.StringVar(value = 'black')

    self._player_text = tkinter.StringVar()

    self._player_text.set('Which player moves first: ')

    player_label = tkinter.Label(
            master = self.root_window, textvariable = self._player_text,
            background = 'yellow', height = 1, width = 20, font = DEFAULT_FONT)

    player_label.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=90, sticky = tkinter.W+tkinter.N)

    for text,mode in PLAYERS:
        first = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.root_window, text = text,
                            variable = self.firstplayer , value = mode)

        first.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 300, pady = 90, sticky = tkinter.W + tkinter.N)

    return self.firstplayer.get()
```

Comment: `-> str` is illegal syntax. What do you expect that to do? Also, tkinter has no class named `Root`; what do you expect `tkinter.Root()` to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are placing both radiobuttons in the same place: row 1, column 0. The first one it thus invisible because it is under the second one. If you want the label and two radiobuttons on the same row but different columns, the solution is to give them all the same row, and different columns.

There are many ways to accomplish this, I'll show you one:

```
column = 1
for text,mode in PLAYERS:
    first = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.root_window, text = text,
                                variable = self.firstplayer , value = mode)
    first.grid(row = 1, column = column, sticky = tkinter.W + tkinter.N)
    column += 1
```

Comment: Even if I switch the numbers to say row 2 col 1, it only still shows white.

Comment: I removed the row and left the column there and changed padx, pady to 0 but it only stays on the bottom now instead of where I want it to be.

Comment: padx and pady have nothing to do with the problem. Each radio button needs a different row and/or column.

Comment: I removed the row and now it just has the column, and now it's the way I want it, but not in the places I want it at. It's on the bottom instead of next to the label. How would I fix it?

Comment: @accelerate: I don't know how you did it, but you seem to be making this more difficult than it needs to be. I've updated my answer to show one possible solution.